# How to extend p5.js's TypeScript definition?

Tags: javascript, typescript, p5.js

I have been trying to use [p5.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p5) with TypeScript, but the definition seems incomplete. For example, the `canvas` property on the `p5` class's instance member is private/not defined, despite existing as `HTMLCanvasElement` in reality.

```
import p5 from 'p5'

// Property 'canvas' does not exist on type...
const sketch = new p5(_ => console.log(sketch.canvas))
```

Since I haven't augmented a module before, I am having difficulty merging my own definitions with the library’s. I wrote something like this in my custom `.d.ts` file:

```
declare module 'p5' {
  interface p5 {
    canvas: HTMLCanvasElement
  }

  export default p5
  export = p5
}
```

Now `sketch.canvas` is defined, but `p5` itself becomes undefined (`Type 'typeof p5' has no construct signatures.`). My goal is to merge my definition with the library’s and not to overwrite everything. I don’t quite understand what I am doing wrong.